# Laravel customize log formatter

Tags: laravel, logging, laravel-5

I want to **customize the log line format** of **only** the **errorlog channel**.
Is it possible to define it in the config file (config/logging.php), or i have to made a class for it as the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/logging#advanced-monolog-channel-customization) says? But it shows me no hint..

Can somebody show me some example?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You will have to create a formatter that implements [this interface](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Formatter/FormatterInterface.php).

Comment: @Jerodev Thanks! But where is defined the elements of the line? How can I implement without primary examples?
actually I want only the message (without timestamp and extra stuff)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest method would be passing your own format to the LineFormatter class:

```
[
    'driver' => 'monolog',
    'formatter' => Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter::class,
    'formatter_with' => [
        'format' => "[%datetime%] %channel%.%level_name%: %message% %context% %extra%\n",
    ],
]
```

You can look at the LineFormatter to see that $format is accepted in the constructor.

You can create your own class implementing the FormatterInterface and look to the ~20 other formatters as examples in the Monolog/Formatter directory.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really like how simple is this solution! :)

Comment: Where do you put this configuration? What file?

Comment: @mpen in `config/logging.php`

Comment: Does the formatter works with other drivers as well? Fos example in my case I use the `sentry` driver instead of the `monolog` one.

Comment: I'd assume not since it's a monolog interface/implementation.  Sentry may have their own method of customizing the format.